# Is there anything called a yellow card for temporary residence in the USA?

Tags: usa, greencard, residence-cards

I know about the green card but I heard this term "yellow card" from relatives that s/he gets a yellow card. They are saying that it means s/he has no problems for eight years. Is it true? Is there any term like yellow card or similar in the process of getting a green card?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. Some old editions of green cards looked kind of yellow-ish. There are also Border Crossing Cards issued to Mexican nationals (basically a visitor visa in card form) but they are not particularly yellow.

Comment: @user102008 Then what was that that s/he has no problem till eight year in usa means they can live there?

Comment: The only context in which I've heard the term "yellow card" is in connection with football (soccer) officiating. I've held a USA green card since 1978.

Comment: Hopefully, s/he is not referring to the [Tea Party proposal of a yellow card](http://agreater.us/billpage.php?id=404) which would be used to track and enforce immigration.

Comment: What country is this relative originally from? I also can't find anything commonly called a "yellow card", but if you could ask your relative what the real name of the card is, someone here could probably explain more about it. If it's a green card, there's no 8-year limitation. Green cards are either conditional (2 year) or permanent (the document expires after 10 years, but not the residency; you just need to renew the document).

Comment: Could it perhaps be an [I-688A](http://www.usborderpatrol.com/Border_Patrol1712_7.htm) or [I-688](http://www.usborderpatrol.com/Border_Patrol1712_8.htm), issued to people under the 1986 amnesty? Those are kind of yellow. But those are rare today. That website contains a good list of pictures of historical US immigration documents.

Comment: @user102008 or maybe it's a scam.

Comment: The only significance of "8 years" that I know of is that green card holders leaving the US are subject to exit tax if they've had the green card for more than 8 years.

Comment: The current 'Green Cards' are not really green, they have a pale yellow. Might be a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever is telling you this is conning you. There is no such thing in the US. If it had been the UK, it could mean a yellow registration certificate for Croatians who are going to study.

But in the US? No.